# How to set alarm for a specific period

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I let the user set a start and an end time for a repeating alarm, e.g. from 2:30 PM to 4:30 PM every day. I can set the alarm to go off at the specified start time but how can I stop it at the end time?

I guess I should handle this in the Broadcast Receiver class where I get the extra and compare it to the system time, but I cannot cancel here the alarm the way I cancel it in an activity.

This is an example of how I set the alarm:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewSchedule.this, RepeatingAlarm.class);
    intent.putExtra("endTime", cal_alarmend.getTimeInMillis()/1000);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NewSchedule.this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarmstart.getTimeInMillis(), 6000, sender);
```

The receiver class:

```
public class RepeatingAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "repeating_received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        long end = b.getLong("endTime");

        Log.i("now", now + "");
        Log.i("end", end + "");


        if (now > end)
        {
            ???????
        }

      }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Why cannot I cancel the alarm in the onReceive() in the BroadcastReceiver?

```
public class RepeatingAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "repeating_received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        long end = b.getLong("endTime");
        int rc = b.getInt("reqCode");

        Log.i("rc", rc + "");

        long n = now/1000;
        long e = end;

        Log.i("now", n + "");
        Log.i("end", e + "");


        if (n > e)
        {
            Log.i("STATUS", "now > end    " + n + ">" + e);
            Intent intentstart = new Intent();
            PendingIntent senderstart = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, rc, intentstart, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.cancel(senderstart);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("STATUS", "now <= end    " + n + "<=" + e);
        }

      }
    }
```

I doublechecked the stacktrace and the rc is exactly the same request code I used to start the alarm.

This is the stacktrace:
[image]

After this, the alarm should have been cancelled, but I still get the Toast message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot cancel here the alarm the way I cancel it in an activity

AFAIK, you can. More accurately, I do not see what would be a problem.

> And this is how I cancel the alarm in an activity

That code sets an alarm. It does not cancel it. To cancel an alarm, create a `PendingIntent` with the same type (e.g., `getBroadcast()`) on an equivalent `Intent` (everything but the extras), and call `cancel()` on the `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I misstyped it. I removed the arguments from the Intent(), but ALARM_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable. How should I modify it?

Comment: @erdomester: `Context.ALARM_SERVICE`.

Comment: Now: The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type RepeatingAlarm (this is the line: <code>AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);</code>)

Comment: @erdomester: If you read the documentation, you will see that [`getSystemService()` is a method on `Context`](http://goo.gl/HLhvj). Also, if you read the documentation, [`BroadcastReceiver` does not inherit from `Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). However, you are supplied a `Context` as a parameter to `onReceive()`. Hence, call `getSystemService()` on that supplied `Context`.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the topic. Could you help why isn't the alarm cancelled when the end time has passed?

Comment: @erdomester: You are using an invalid `Intent`. You are scheduling the alarm with `new Intent(NewSchedule.this, RepeatingAlarm.class)`, but you are trying to cancel `new Intent()`.

Comment: I noticed that. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: @erdomester: In the `()` of your presently-empty `Intent` constructor, type `context, RepeatingAlarm.class`.